# RubyGems + Cygwin: POSIX path not found by ruby.exe

Tags: ruby, bash, rubygems, cygwin

I am a Ruby programmer on Windows who trys to switch from Win cmd to Cygwin, but cannot achieve to execute batch files of Ruby gems.

I already stuffed any bin directory into the Windows `PATH` env. variable, including the Ruby bin where the executables are stored. Gems, however, are invoked by ruby.exe itself, which leads to the following problem with POSIX paths:

```
duddle@duddledan /cygdrive/c/Ruby/ruby-186-398/bin
$ gem -v
C:\Ruby\ruby-186-398\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Ruby/ruby-186-398/bin/gem (LoadError)

duddle@duddledan /cygdrive/c/Ruby/ruby-186-398/bin
$ ./gem --version
1.3.7
```

When calling e.g. `./gem` directly by specifying the path, it can be found and executed.

Any ideas?

*Edit:*

*How to tell cygwin not to process batch files?*

Comment: See `man cygpath` to see if it has anything helpful.

Comment: What about changing the answer in the other one (+12 votes)?

Comment: I cannot validate it because I don't use Windows anymore. Can we make this to a community question or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to mix batch files which expect native paths with Cygwin, which completely dislike it.

When you call ./gem you're invoking the ruby script, but using the `PATH` is invoking the batch file.

Either you tell cygwin not to process batch files (dunno how) or you use MSYS Bash if you want a replacement of cmd.exe, but don't mix Cygwin with native Ruby.

I've blogged about mixing and matching in the past:

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2008/10/27/handy-tip-dont-mix-one-click-installer-with-cygwin/

Comment: Ok... reading your blogpost... how would I use the bundled Ruby version of Cygwin... and what would be the disadvantages of doing so? Can/Must I also install all other tools relying on native extensions within the Cygwin environment? ImageMagick, nokogiri, etc, etc.? Does that slow things down? Or will I encounter other problems?

Comment: Yes, it will be slower and yes, you will need to install everything under cygwin Ruby because compiled code is different.

Comment: A recommendation is use MSYS, because if you only need bash, then you don't need the slowness of cygwin in everything.

Answer (score 59):

You can mix and match Cygwin with MingW32 Ruby if you are careful and there are good reasons for doing so. Cygwin provides a more fleshed out CLI environment than does MSYS but Cygwin's bundled Ruby is much slower than the MingW32 version.  The trick is to alias all the RubyGem wrappers in your Cygwin .bashrc.  Here is a snippet from mine.

```
alias gem='gem.bat'
alias rake='rake.bat'
alias erb='erb.bat'
alias irb='irb.bat'
alias rdoc='rdoc.bat'
alias ri='ri.bat'
alias rspec='rspec.bat'
alias cucumber='cucumber.bat'
alias bundle='bundle.bat'
```

Comment: This is the real answer. Thanks so much! I just got my environment working nicely, so I will be able to ditch the windows cmd.exe shell.

Comment: I agree this fix's this problem (saved me a headache just a moment ago) but i think Luis has the real answer.  These are just stopgaps until the next problem.

Comment: I found it useful to also add `alias compass='compass.bat'`

Answer (score 18):

The trick is to alias all `.bat` files as Robert pointed out in his answer.

Adding a new alias to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` after every `gem install` ain't fun though ...

Therefore i create these **aliases automatically** by scanning Ruby's bindir:

```
if [[ -n "$(which ruby 2>/dev/null)" ]]; then
  RUBY_BIN=$(cygpath -u $(ruby -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["bindir"]') | tr '\r' ' ')
  for f in $(find ${RUBY_BIN} -regex ".*bat$"| xargs -n1 basename); do
      alias ${f%.bat}=${f}
  done
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think the second string should be
RUBY_BIN=$(cygpath -u $(ruby -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["bindir"]') | tr -d '\r')

Comment: In a windows box I use with babun/zsh, the find was failing, so I removed the  | tr -d '\r' piece and changed the find path to  ${RUBY_BIN: : -1}

Comment: I created a GIST based on @Oswaldo comment. You can grab it here: https://gist.github.com/thomaseizinger/08d8bde9bf814ca75805d962cc101e72