# Error when trying to invoke the rails command via Cygwin on windows (installed via railsinstaller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, cygwin

I have followed [this tutorial](http://railsinstaller.org/) for installing ruby on rails on windows. (the steps are explained in the video in the middle of the page)

If I run the rails command in a classic windows shell (`windows + r` > `cmd` > `enter`), it works fine. However, I would like to be able to invoke it in a cygwin shell. But if I do, for example:

```
$> rails s # in cygwin
```

I have the following error:

> C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory --
>   /cygdrive/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails (LoadError)

I've looked into this folder:`C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\`, and there is indeed no rails.exe, but only a rails and rails.bat file.

rails.bat looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "C:/Projects/railsinstaller/stage/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

I only know that cygwin looks for .exe files (for example, if you type `cp`, is it going to execute the `cp.exe` executable). I don't know how .bat files works.

So do you know how I can make cygwin able to invoke the rails command ?

Comment: If you want to do Rails development professionally, you should seriously consider buying a mac (macbook air or pro).

Answer (score 2):

As you've stated, the rails on windows is a ".bat" file. Just use the ".bat" extension in every command. It worked for me.

Try and see: "rails.bat -v" (in Cygwin)

Comment: this does not answer the question

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue in cygwin but the "rails" command was working fine in windows cmd prompt. As a turn around
Invoke the following command in cygwin,
`alias rails='path_to_ruby_installed_directory/bin/rails.bat'`

In your case,
`alias rails ='C:/Projects/railsinstaller/stage/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails.bat'`

To make the alias permanent,
Edit the .bashrc file in CYGWIN home directory and add the above alias in it.

Comment: it should be alias not aias (I tried editing but not enough characters to complete the edit).

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use Cygwin since everything is set up for use with Command Prompt. You may be able to get git-bash working but the Command Prompt included with RI is the supported method of using RailsInstaller. If you want to use Cygwin, I'd suggest not using RailsInstaller.

Comment: unfortunately if you're running from an IDE like Aptana 3 which uses cygwin, there is no way around it.

Comment: Diwas, if using Aptana, you can still use the Command Prompt but it just won't be integrated into the IDE. Unfortunately, this is the issue with using an IDE versus just a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I've been suffer from this problem for such a long time, and I've just found an workaround, In cygwin terminal:

ln -s path-of-you-rails-installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe /bin/ruby
ln -s path-of-you-rails-installer/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails.bat /bin/rails

ps: the full path is gonna be something like: /cygdrive/d/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe

and then rails can be invoked within cygwin.

Comment: ln -s /cygdrive/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe /bin/ruby ln -s /cygdrive/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails.bat /bin/rails

errors out saying - /bin/rails is not a folder

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .bashrc or .zshrc to create alias for all appropriate `.bat`:

```
# cygwin
if [[ -n "$(which ruby 2>/dev/null)" ]]; then
  RUBY_BIN=$(cygpath -u $(ruby -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["bindir"]') | tr -d '\r')
  for f in $(find ${RUBY_BIN} -regex ".*bat$"| xargs -n1 basename); do
    alias ${f%.bat}=${f}
  done
fi
```

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/19424481/1248256