# Is there a way to make rubyinstaller play nice with cygwin?

Tags: ruby, windows, cygwin, rake

I was having trouble getting jekyll to work with Ruby using cygwin on Windows 7 64-bit. I had better results using rubyinstaller + devkit. It would be really nice if I could use the rubyinstaller ruby inside of cygwin.

However, I get the following message when I try to execute rake.

```
$ rake page name="pages/about.md"
C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Ruby193/bin/rake (LoadError)
```

Is there any way to make rubyinstaller play nice with cygwin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RubyGems + Cygwin: POSIX path not found by ruby.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831131/rubygems-cygwin-posix-path-not-found-by-ruby-exe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is cygwin converting all the scripts paths into cygwin paths (`/cygdrive/...`).

There is no solution for that since the invoke of the script is made from bash over `rake` scrip which invokes native Ruby.

There are a lot of other issues that cygwin will cause, and some are covered in [RubyInstaller troubleshooting page](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-cygwin)

One alternative will be invoking `rake.bat` directly, skipping cygwin shebang detection.

But cygwin doesn't like batch files, which forces you to do `cmd.exe /C rake.bat` and that is a noisy command line.

The other alternative is install something like [gem-exefy](https://github.com/bosko/gem-exefy) (`gem install gem-exefy`) and generate executables for your installed gems (`rake.exe`).

That way you invoke `rake.exe` instead of letting cygwin figure it out.

Another alternative is use MSYS Bash (included in DevKit) instead of cygwin, which plays way better than cygwin one, but you will still have issues with batch files.

As you can see, mixing non-native (cygwin) with native (RubyInstaller) have a lot of side-effects.

Comment: Thanks! I went the gem-exefy route.  A minor inconvience to include the .exe extension but now at least I don't have to use both cmd.exe and cygwin :)

Answer (score 39):

I just put a few of these in my .bash_profile:

```
alias gem=gem.bat
alias irb=irb.bat
alias rake=rake.bat
```

I never have any of the problems that Luis mentions.

Comment: Interesting, cygwin 1.7? I had a bunch of problems with cygwin trying to read batch files and failing to interpret them properly. Happy to hear batch files worked for you :)

Comment: Yes, the trick may be to just make sure they are in your PATH and don't use the full path when you run them

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the right answer. All I had to do to get jekyll to work was to create an alias for it.

Comment: I tried the same method for pry: `alias pry=pry.bat` but didn't worked =( Any clues why? Thanks

Comment: is pry.bat in your PATH?