# How do I configure Cygwin to search using the PATHEXT environment variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, cygwin

I am trying to run Rails under Cygwin but when I type "rails -v" it finds "rails" and throws an error.  When I type "rails.bat -v" it works just fine.  Either works fine in the native Windows command processor because it uses PATHEXT to identify executables like .BAT.

I added a line to .bash_profile as follows and it is setting the variable, as far as I can tell.

```
export PATHEXT=".RB;.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC"
```

This is my output:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/WIDCOMM/Bluetooth Software:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/WIDCOMM/Bluetooth Software/syswow64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/7-Zip:/cygdrive/d/sysinternals:/cygdrive/d/batch:/cygdrive/d/Program Files/Sublime Text 2:/cygdrive/d/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin:/cygdrive/d/RailsInstaller/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/d/RailsInstaller/Git/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/d/batch

 18:54~
$ echo $PATHEXT
.RB;.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

 18:54~
$ which rails
/cygdrive/d/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails

 18:54~
$ which rails.bat
/cygdrive/d/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails.bat

 18:55~
$ rails -v
D:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/d/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails (LoadError)

 18:55~
$ rails.bat -v
Rails 3.2.11

 18:55~
$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Railsinstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) ruby binary, which is basically a redistribution of [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) with some of the essentials for Rails development bundled.

However, everything is actually working as intended.

Cygwin doesn't won't use `PATHTEXT` because it doesn't need to. In other words, it will call the `rails` binstub instead of the `rails.bat` batch file. Since there is a `hashbang` in the binstubs, cygwin handles the entire execution itself.

Also, the RubyInstaller distribution wasn't compiled for Cygwin. So `ruby.exe` doesn't understand the look-up of the Cygwin paths. That is why you're getting a `LoadError`.

In my opinion, you should probably check out [this answer by Luis Lavena to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12252443/527152). However, if you really want to, you can recompile Ruby in Cygwin or get a Cygwin Ruby distribution.

Comment: I tried using the second answer provided in your referenced link, not the first and accepted answer.  It uses alias commands to translate rails to rails.bat.  It appears to be working but I'll be looking for side effects.  I am going to have to consider going full native, though.

Answer (score 0):

(In Windows using RailsInstaller) The only way for me was to do add and alias to the installation path.

```
alias rails='C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails'
```

Once I typed that within cygwin terminal, it worked just fine.